# Will MacBook be re-added to Find My?

Tags: find-my

I have lost my MacBook. I went onto Find My on another Mac and it was offline. Accidentally, I removed the device from the Sidebar and saw the following popup, again I accidentally clicked "Remove".

Will this Mac reappear in Find My when it connects to the Internet?

[image: Remove Mac?]

Answer (score 2):

No, you have permanently unlinked the machine from your AppleID. Your account would have to be manually re-enabled on the MacBook.